# Proof that every non-empty subset of a woset (X, $\leq$) has a unique minimal element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I want to prove that every nonempty subset of a woset (X, $\leq$) has a unique minimal element.

What I’m looking for: clarification and/or hints. I want to solve it on my own, but this is all the information I have been given about the problem, so I need a bit of a nudge in the right direction.

EDIT: I decided to delete my proof in case someone else wants spoiler-free hints to this problem.

Comment: Wot is a woset?

Comment: Hint: Look at the definition of a well-ordered set.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have, and here it is as given in my textbook: “A well-ordering of a set x is a well-founded, total ordering of x. A well-ordered set (or woset) is a pair (x, $\leq$) such that $\leq$ is a well-ordering of x.” I don’t see what can help me there. I’m very new to set-theory, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: The answer by Rise does rhe job, if you look up the definition of well-founded.

Comment: There's hardly anything to prove. Look up the definition of "well-founded".

Comment: If "woset" means well-ordered set, then this is a definition.  If a linearly ordered set has a non-empty subset without a minimum, then the order is not a well-order. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

By definition, a well- ordered set is a set $X$ with a **total** ordering '$\leq$' with the property that every non-empty subset of $X$ has a minimal element.

So if $A$ is a non-empty subset of $X$ then obviously it has a minimal element. Now suppose $a$ and $b$ are two minimal elements of $A$ what does total ordering say?

Comment: Oh! I think that got me onto something. Would the proof include using the antisymmetry property of partial ordering, or am I going in the wrong direction with that?

Comment: The uniqueness uses the antisymmetry property.